# cannot access my json response data outside the ngOnInit() in my Angular 4.x app

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I have an Angular 4.x app with a http request that is getting sent and I am getting back valid json from the endpoint (I can see this in the initial console.log) - the problem is I cannot see this data outside on the ngOnInit() just below where I have the console.log

Can anyone suggest what the issue is?

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

   ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('https://dev.myapp.com/api/angularfour/auth',
        { params: new HttpParams()
            .set('token', this.userService.getAuth().__token)
            .set('apiversion', '1')
            .set('appid', this.userService.getAuth().appid) })
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log('data', data); // can see this data
        });
    }

console.log('menu data outside init', data); // cannot see this data?
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about the scope of the variables, in your exemple; data exist only in the subscribe method, you need to define a global variable in your class for example :

Under export class add :

```
mydata : any;
```

and in your subscribe method :

```
this.mydata = data;
```

So you can access data outside method :

```
console.log('menu data outside init', this.mydata);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set a property on your component if you want to access it outside of the `ngOnInit` block. Right now, your `data` variable is scoped to the `subscribe` block in your `ngOnInit` method.

Try something like this:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

data: any; // property for data

ngOnInit() {

this.http.get('https://dev.myapp.com/api/angularfour/auth',
    { params: new HttpParams()
        .set('token', this.userService.getAuth().__token)
        .set('apiversion', '1')
        .set('appid', this.userService.getAuth().appid) })
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data; // save the most recent data in the data property
        console.log('data', data); // can see this data
    });
}

console.log('menu data outside init', this.data); // your data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
   myData:any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) { }

   ngOnInit() {

    this.http.get('https://dev.myapp.com/api/angularfour/auth',
        { params: new HttpParams()
            .set('token', this.userService.getAuth().__token)
            .set('apiversion', '1')
            .set('appid', this.userService.getAuth().appid) })
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log('data', data); // can see this data
            this.myData=data;
        });
    }

   buttonClick(){
     console.log('menu data outside init',  this.myData); 
     // this will only work after the async call has finished
    }
}
```